# Apache POI - xml:space="preserve" in .xlsx is crashing GUI, and badly formatted cell

Tags: java, android, xml, excel, apache-poi

I have following document: [supl_zak.xlsx](https://mega.nz/#!etoyVSyA!bt7Lbf8A9__irLO-FUX4OF3AI7LzzXFU41lRENRzihY). My output from G6 is:

```
10-20 12:55:38.521 30921-30921/tona_kriz.kriziksupl I/System.out: Row: 8 - Column: 7 =
```

(yes, nothing) and the GUI will disappear (crash?) but the whole app still runs. It reads good every other one-line string not ending with space.

I explored that .xlsx file and found string for that cell:

```
<t xml:space="preserve">Tv/Jk=0 ------- </t>
```

How to make it not crashing and with output like [this?](http://s18.postimg.org/56kgjqkux/Screen_Lock.png)

(yes, I used Gimp to make it look like this :P, but transparency failed. PS: text colour does not matter, I used wrong colour.)

*My source is:*

**MainActivity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int wbs;
    XSSFWorkbook wb = null;
    XSSFSheet sheet = null;
    XSSFCell cell;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //1. Open the file
        new Thread(loadWorkbook).start();
    }


    public Runnable loadWorkbook = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                AssetManager assManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
                InputStream is = null;
                try {
                    is = assManager.open("supl_zak.xlsx");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                wb = new XSSFWorkbook(caInput);
                wbs = wb.getNumberOfSheets();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    workWithWB();
                }
            });
        }


    };

    void workWithWB() {
        //3. Get each cell by row & column number
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "number of sheets: " + wbs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        cell = sheet.getRow(7).getCell(5);
        String stringVal = cell.getStringCellValue();
        TextView test = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        test.setText(stringVal);
        try {
            wb.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**libraries**
https://github.com/andruhon/AndroidReadXLSX

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries false
        //incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        tasks.matching {
            it.name.startsWith('dex')
        }.each { dx ->
            if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
                dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
            } else {
                dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
           }
        }
    }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "awesomeapp.whichreadsexcell"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.0.0.0.1 closed pre alpha"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    project.tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex) {
        additionalParameters=['--core-library'] // --core-library option needed for now, will fix it soon
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile files('libs/poi-3.12-android.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511.jar')
}
```

Any solution for me? May I record (bandicam, fraps, ..) emulator and logcat how it looks?

**logcat** added

```
10-22 20:14:26.435 31444-31444 I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
10-22 20:14:26.525 31444-31444 W/ActivityThread: Application tona_kriz.kriziksupl can be debugged on port 8100...
10-22 20:14:26.555 31444-31444 I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
10-22 20:14:26.555 31444-31444 I/MultiDex: install
10-22 20:14:26.555 31444-31444 I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
10-22 20:14:26.555 31444-31444 V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = tona_kriz.kriziksupl
10-22 20:14:26.555 31444-31444 V/Monotype:     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default
10-22 20:14:26.565 31444-31444 V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = tona_kriz.kriziksupl
10-22 20:14:26.565 31444-31444 V/Monotype:     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default
10-22 20:14:26.575 31444-31444 I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
```

Comment: Why is it crashing? What error / exception are you seeing? And what happens if you try with Apache POI 3.13?

Comment: It crashed when I am trying to write that cell to string 'String stringVal = cell.getStringCellValue();' or when I am trying to set it as text of textview (xml not needed, its just simple textview without any changes)   'test = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView); test.setText(stringVal);' . In console (logcat) there are nothing

Comment: I can post full log cat in evening.

Comment: You don't appear to be doing any checks on the type of the cell. What happens if you put those in, eg as per the [Apache POI docs on getting a cell value](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents)?

Comment: @Gagravarr my code looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/GP6NAVzF) now and still crashing...

Comment: edit: Added logcat...